# The bounds of UIScrollView in viewDidLoad are not same size as set in IB

Tags: ios

I have a UIScrollView in a storyboard and its height is set as either 548 or 460 depending upon the device, i.e. the full size of the screen excluding the status bar (see screen shots).

However when I run the code and examine its bounds then the size is either 568 or 480 in viewDidLoad:

```
CGRect frame = self.slideshowScrollView.bounds; 
// frame.origin.y gets set to 480 or 568 not 460 or 548.
```

Why is the bounds including the size of the status bar when IB isn't?

(The UIScrollView is within a UIView, the size of this in IB is also 548 or 460 and it too is coming out in viewDidLoad as 480 or 568).
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's the view in? Is the view owned by a view controller that was just displayed? Does the view frame change too?

Comment: The view is owned by the view controller shown in the first screen shot, the UIScrollView is within the view. The VC is just loaded and I  have the code snippet shown in its viewDidLoad: as mentioned. The view's bounds are also 480 or 568, however within IB its height is set to 548 or 460 the same as the UIScrollView.

Comment: First off, are you using auto-layout in IB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wants full screen screen attribute for the view controller was set in IB, this was the cause of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on frame sizes to be set properly when viewDidLoad is called, whether for your main view or its subviews.  Instead you might consider viewWillAppear.  If you check the size in viewWillAppear is it correct there?

Comment: Its the same result in viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

Check the `UIView` Property set `Statusbar` property as `default` or as you want. It will solve your problem.